# Paste vs PasteSpecial

Tags: vba, excel

After two hours of futile search and frustration. I am posting the question here.

Can anyone please explain the detailed difference between paste and pastespecial option in excel vba?

Or cite some resources which can help

Comment: I found a useful link, Please go through this http://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's simple :

---

**Paste** will paste exactly what's in the origin range (to make it simple: values or formulas)

---

**PasteSpecial** let you define what you want to paste (value, formula, style, etc..).

With:

```
expression .PasteSpecial(Paste, Operation, SkipBlanks, Transpose)
```

The first argument `Paste` is of [XlPasteType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx) type that determines what you can choose

---

Some further read:

[MSDN Range.PasteSpecial Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)

[The PasteSpecial VBA Command: Get VBA to Do the Hard Work for You](https://blog.udemy.com/pastespecial-vba/)

Answer (score -2):

**Paste** only duplicates the data as it was on its previous location, while **Paste Special**, being a little wittier, has the ability to duplicate the function or formula applied to previous range of cells. After you apply the Paste Special command, it will apply the same formula or function with the ranges of cell relative to the new location.