# How to copy and paste and retain the data validation?

Tags: excel, vba

The data is 100% right.

I want to paste the data into the cell with data validation and keep the data validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give any context. I assume you're copying with VBA. If your code copies and then uses .PasteSpecial with a Paste type of xlPasteValues, formatting of the destination cell (including data validation) will be retained ... an example being ...

```
Public Sub test()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValidation)
End Sub
```

Also refer to: [Paste vs PasteSpecial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810625/paste-vs-pastespecial)

Comment: I didn't think it needed it. I knew it was a stupid question I just couldn't find the awnser and was searching for 20min. Thank you

Comment: This didn't work for me - the data validation was not retained. I had to use: `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation`

Comment: @PeterX ... you're right. Can't see what I was thinking. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA example of how to add the validation back after any change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Range("Table1[Column1]").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertWarning, Operator _
        :=xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""Table2"")"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = False
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```