# Excel VBA: Bypassing clipboard when copying values

Tags: excel, vba, copy, out-of-memory, excel-2016

I am trying to copy information from one file to another. As read [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm), there are more and less efficient ways of doing this.

Currently, I am using a less efficient method:

```
Target_Sheet.Cells.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

This works on my Excel (2016, 64 bit), but on some computers I get an out of memory error. However, when I tried the following statement, I immediately get an out of memory error:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name").Cells.Value = Target_Sheet.Cells.Value
```

**Why does this happen? The method is supposed to be more efficient.**

Alternatively, I want to use the copy-method and bypass the clipboard using something like the following code. But how can I specify that I only want values?

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:A200").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("B1")
```

Comment: Instead of copying all the cells (which is a lot!), just copy the `Usedrange` of the sheet.

Comment: @Rory UsedRange indeed makes the copying a bit easier. Thanks for the suggestion. However, I cannot use UsedRange with .Value that simply, given the ranges may have different sizes.

Comment: You can, you simply resize the target range using the size of the source's `Usedrange`.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few questions in your post:

1.**Why does this happen?**

Because you are handling the entire set of cells. This is way too big thus the "out of memory" error.
the faulty bit in your code is this part: `.Cells.Value`. To prevent targeting all the cells, you need to specify a range as described below.

2.**How to use copy/paste with values only**

Actually the only way is to do it the way you initially wrote it (apart from the `.Cells` part) in your "less efficient method". You first copy the range, it is then stored in the clipboard, next you decide on a destination and finally you use the "paste" function. You can see this other question for [additional details on "paste" vs "paste special"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810625/paste-vs-pastespecial).
So if you replace `.Cells` by `.UsedRange` you should already see a speed improvement.

3.**How to make a more efficient copy**

I understand that this is what you truly want answered.
Given that you seem to be unsure about the source range dimensions, I recommend you to copy to entire sheet.

```
Target_Sheet.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name")
```

If this does not suit your needs, you should match the different sizes of the origin range and of the destination range. As mentioned in the comments, this can be done with `UsedRange`.

```
dim rowOrigin as long
dim colOrigin as long
dim rowEnd as long
dim colEnd as long
Dim Origin_Sheet As Worksheet: Set Origin_Sheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Destination_Sheet As Worksheet: Set Destination_Sheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

colEnd = Origin_Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
rowEnd = Origin_Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
colOrigin = Origin_Sheet.UsedRange.Column
rowOrigin = Origin_Sheet.UsedRange.Row

Destination_Sheet.Range(Destination_Sheet.Cells(rowOrigin, colOrigin), Destination_Sheet.Cells(rowEnd, colEnd)).Value = _
    Origin_Sheet.Range(Origin_Sheet.Cells(rowOrigin, colOrigin), Origin_Sheet.Cells(rowEnd, colEnd)).Value
```

Comment: Hi GTPV, thank you for your answer. I first tried your last solution, but unfortunately I get a 1004 error. Do you know how that may have happened? And you said you recommended to copy the entire sheet, is that more efficient than copying a range?

Comment: Regarding efficiency of copying the sheet vs the range, it depends on the size of the range and it also depends on the logic required for copying the range. If you need to stitch together a lot of smaller ranges then it might be easier to just plain copy the whole sheet and be done with it. I also proposed that because your first solution was attempting to copy the whole sheet by copying all the cells.

Comment: Regarding the error, I admit that I have assumed that all your cells were normal data cells, is that the case? If you have any shape/chart/picture/table then the copying may require extra step depending on you wanting or not to copy them fully or partially.
Also, make sure that "Target_Sheet" is defined. I edited the answer to reflect that.